# Stop asking to copy file location to clipboard while using Visual Foxpro 9 HtmlListener

Tags: visual-foxpro

For the first time in my life, I actually need to ASK a question because for the life of me I cannot actually seem to find an answer on here or MSDN.

The following code works as expected:

```
SET CLASSLIB TO HOME()+ 'FFC\_REPORTLISTENER'
loHTMLReporter = CREATEOBJECT('htmlListener')

loHTMLReporter.TARGETFILENAME = 'MYFILENAME'
REPORT FORM MYREPORT OBJECT loHTMLReporter
```

However, after the report is generated, it asks me if I would like to copy the location of the file to clipboard. I was wondering if there was a property I could set on the html listener after creation, or when I actually tell VFP to run the report that would stop this behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML Listener is derived from the XMLListener in the same class library
which is derived from UtilityReportListner
which is derived from FxListener
which is derived from _reportListener
```

Then a simple property...

```
loHTMLReporter.QuietMode = .T.
```

then run your report...

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you!